# How to use component fields in file-uploader onErrorItem callback?

Tags: angular, file-upload

Is there is a way to use angular component class fields in file-uploader onErrorItem callback?

```
private AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";
  errorEventHandler(item: any, response: string, status: number, headers: ParsedResponseHeaders): any {
    console.log(this.AUTH_HEADER); //prints undefined
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how do you use errorEventHandler mehod? maybe you lose context?

if you use it like

```
foo().subscribe(this.errorEventHandler)
```

you need to bind context of component

```
foo().subscribe(this.errorEventHandler.bind(this))
```